# Static property of inner static class of non-static class shared between instances of the non-static class?

Tags: c#, .net, inner-classes, static-members

An example is worth a thousand stupid questions so:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public static class InnerClassEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public static int SomeInt;
    }
}
```

and in a galaxy far far away:

```
public void SomeFunkyFunc()
{
    OuterClass Instance1;
    OuterClass Instance2;

    Instance1.InnerClassEventArgs.SomeInt = 1;
    Instance2.InnerClassEventArgs.SomeInt = 2;

    //WHAT WOULD Instance1.InnerClassEventArgs.Someint == ?
}
```

Yes, I realize now that I've typed this that I've almost coded all I need to answer my own question. I'd rather not create a new project and go through the trouble if someone smarter than me knows off the top of their head.

Comment: It would be 2 - it's a static variable - it represents the last assigned value

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Instance1.InnerClassEventArgs.SomeInt` would equal 2. Static fields are shared across all instances of the class -- or [as MSDN puts it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx):

> The static member is always accessed by the class name, not the instance name. Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created.

Note that your specific example won't compile -- you'll get an error message that says "Cannot access static class 'InnerClassEventArgs' in a non-static context."

You'd have to use the following code instead, which hopefully makes the behavior more understandable:

```
OuterClass.InnerClassEventArgs.SomeInt = 1;
OuterClass.InnerClassEventArgs.SomeInt = 2;
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't compile at all: `Cannot reference a type through an expression`

Comment: Ah, good point on the NullReference. Am I allowed to say thanks right here?

Answer (score 0):

A static class has exactly one instance, "shared" by all its usages (in your case, all instances of OuterClass). Therefore, the state of that object will be the sum of all changes made by any usage. In this simple example, SomeInt will be 2, regardless of which OuterClass instance you used to access it again (Instance1 or Instance2).

I'm conveniently ignoring all of the following:

- A static class cannot inherit from any other class. InnerClassEventArgs thus cannot inherit from EventArgs.
- Instance1 and Instance2 are not initialized; this will cause its own compile-time error if you use ReSharper ("X may not be initialized before accessing").
- Static members (including nested static classes) cannot be accessed based on any one instance; you would access InnerClassEventArgs in static context.